# Using firebase to store data for xml generation

Tags: javascript, html, xml, json, firebase

From what I understand in the documentation of firebase, data you input is converted into JSON right? Now in order for you to connect to firebase, the easiest way is to use javascript. But what if you use the JSON data in firebase to create an XML file? Is this possible?

Comment: You asked this a few days ago too. Please don't delete your original question if you don't get the answer you'd like. My response in this case is the same: yes, you can store XML in Firebase. You'll have to convert it into JSON. If you Google "convert JSON into XML using JavaScript" you should get plenty of hits to get you started. But unless you've already tried something like this, this question shows a lack of effort (which leads to downvotes) and is too broad to be answered (which leads to close votes).

Comment: Thanks. I got this about 4 hours ago. I did it by using the firebase-php by ktamas and used the functions there to connect to firebase and view the stored JSON. Converted it to xml by using json_decode(). I deleted the other questions because it seems that I can't edit it in my previous account. Thanks for the reminder anyway!

Comment: If you have code and are stuck somewhere, show the code and explain where you're stuck. It will show us the direction you're taking (not to mention the fact that you're using PHP and not HTML) and makes people more likely to help you solve your problem. "Is this possible?" is one of the worst types of questions you can ask on StackOverflow, because it can correctly be answered with "Yes" and you'll be none the wiser. But "I have this code that I expect to do A. Can you explain why it does B instead?" is much more likely to get a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a parser to convert JSON -> XML then save the XML content to a file.